# JOptionPane in several lines

Tags: java, joptionpane

In my code I have everything display in one line. I would like that button1, button2, button3, button4 in a column and label1 and two in an other one.

Somebody can help me please ? I think that javax.swing.ButtonGroup can do the job but when I search examples on Internet I find only complex code...

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Container;
    import java.awt.EventQueue;
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;
    import java.awt.Font;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
    import javax.swing.Timer;
    import javax.swing.UIManager;
    import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

    public class RadioButtonV3 extends JFrame{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            new RadioButtonV3();
        }

        public RadioButtonV3() 
        {
            EventQueue.invokeLater
            (
                new Runnable() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try 
                        {
                            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                        } 
                        catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) 
                        {

                        }


                        Container c = getContentPane();     
                        c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

                        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                        final JRadioButton button1 = new JRadioButton("option 1");
                        final JRadioButton button2 = new JRadioButton("option 2");
                        final JRadioButton button3 = new JRadioButton("option 3");
                        final JRadioButton button4 = new JRadioButton("option 4");

                        String s = "this text will be deleted in -> public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)";

                        JLabel label1 = new JLabel(s, JLabel.CENTER);
                        JLabel label2 = new JLabel(s, JLabel.CENTER);
                        label1.setFont(new Font("DigifaceWide Regular", Font.PLAIN, 20));
                        label2.setFont(new Font("DigifaceWide Regular", Font.PLAIN, 20));

                        Timer t = new Timer
                        (
                            500, new ActionListener() 
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                                {


                                    Double rand = Math.random();
                                    label1.setText(rand.toString());
                                    if (rand < 0.3) {
                                        label1.setForeground(Color.RED);
                                    }
                                    else if (rand < 0.6) {
                                        label1.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        label1.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
                                    }

                                    rand = Math.random();
                                    label2.setText(rand.toString());
                                    if (rand < 0.3) {
                                        label2.setForeground(Color.RED);
                                    }
                                    else if (rand < 0.6) {
                                        label2.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        label2.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
                                    }



                                }
                            }
                        );
                        t.setRepeats(true);
                        t.start();






                        panel.add(button1);
                        panel.add(button2);
                        panel.add(button3);
                        panel.add(button4);
                        panel.add(label1);
                        panel.add(label2);

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel, "title", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                        t.stop();
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Change your code

```
Container c = getContentPane();     
  c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

  final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
  final JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
  final JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
  panel.add(panel1);
  panel.add(panel2);
```

and then in the end

```
  panel1.add(button1);
  panel1.add(button2);
  panel1.add(button3);
  panel1.add(button4);
  panel2.add(label1);
  panel2.add(label2);
```